# How to avoid type safety warnings with generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am writing a custom iterator but I am seeing different warnings in my Java code.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomIterator<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> a = Arrays.asList("alpha", "beta", "gamma");
        List<Integer> b = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        // Type safety: The constructor CustomIterator(Iterator...) belongs to the raw type CustomIterator. References to generic type CustomIterator<E> should be parameterized
        CustomIterator it = new CustomIterator(a.iterator(), b.iterator());
        // some logic
    }

    // Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter iterators
    public CustomIterator(Iterator<E>... iterators) {
        // some logic
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I just added the warnings as comments in above code.

It occurs at 2 places:

```
// Type safety: The constructor CustomIterator(Iterator...) belongs to the raw type CustomIterator. References to generic type CustomIterator<E> should be parameterized
CustomIterator it = new CustomIterator(a.iterator(), b.iterator());
```

and also here:

```
// Type safety: Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter iterators
    public CustomIterator(Iterator<E>... iterators) {
        // some logic
    }
```

I can use `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })` to suppress them but I want to know why I am getting these and how to avoid them without suppressing.

Comment: You probably can't avoid suppressing them.   What you are doing has real type-safety issues.   There is actually no type `E` that you could safely instantiate this ... apart from `Object`.  In other words, you don't get any benefit from using generics here.

Comment: You need a declaration like `@SafeVarargs public CustomIterator(Iterator<? extends E>... iterators)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't safely pass two `Iterator`s of different element types (`Iterator<String>` and `Iterator<Integer>` to your `CustomIterator` constructor.

If you hadn't used raw types (as in `CustomIterator it`), the compiler would have told you so. The following, for example, won't pass compilation:

```
CustomIterator<Integer> it = new CustomIterator<Integer>(a.iterator(), b.iterator());
```

Comment: @Michael no, `CustomIterator<Object> it = new CustomIterator<Object>(a.iterator(), b.iterator());` doesn't pass compilation (unless you change `a` and `b` to `List<Object>`).